# Puppet: manifest: optional parameter within class declaration

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet manifest to apply, however, depending on the target, the puppet module defined class does not support certain parameters, whereas it will on other target.

```
e.g. on targetA init.pp: 
   class myclass (
       $foo = undef,
       $bar = undef)
```

```
On targetB init.pp:
      class myclass(
           $foo = undef)
```

Is there a method to variably change the parameters in the declaration without modifying the module already installed on target?

i.e. on targetA, (running puppet version 5.x):

```
                file {‘extra.conf’:
                       ensure => present}
                 ->
                 class {‘::myclass’:
                       foo => ‘myfoo’
                      }
```

while on target B, (running puppet version 4.x):

```
                file {‘extra.conf’:
                       ensure => present|
                 -> 
                 class {‘::myclass’:
                      foo => ‘myfoo’,
                      bar => ‘mybar’
                  }
```

However, if declare the class in this way on target A, an error would occur due to the extra ‘bar’ parameter.  Is there a way to keep the modules (both named 'myclass') while making the manifest portable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the modules (both named 'myclass') while making the manifest portable?

Yes.

### Option 1 - automatic data binding

Put the class parameters in hiera data, use `include`-like class declarations instead of resource-like class declarations, and rely on automatic data binding.  You can put the same data on each node, as automatic data binding looks only for values for classes' defined parameters -- it will ignore keys, no matter the form, that don't correspond to class parameters.

### Option 2 - conditional statements

Puppet DSL has a fairly rich suite of conditional statements that you can use to select a declaration appropriate to the actual target node.  The real trick here is what condition to use to distinguish, because there is no easy way to directly test whether the class supports a specific parameter.  You could certainly distinguish by `$hostname` or `$certname`, but if there are more than two machines then you might want something more generic, such as `$server_facts['serverversion']`.

For example,

```
  case $server_facts['serverversion'] {
    # Puppet version 4
    /^4[.]/: { class { '::myclass': foo => 'myfoo' } }

    # Anything else
    default: { class { '::myclass': foo => 'myfoo', bar => 'mybar' } }
  }

  file { 'extra.conf':
    ensure => 'present',
    before => Class['::myclass'],
  }
```

Comment: Thanks John, I tried Option 2 and it works well. Regarding Option 1, the hieradata is defined, but I wasn't sure if there was a way to override the hieradata within this manifest locally.

Comment: @sround, overriding the Hiera data (with respect to automatic data binding) within the manifest is exactly what is achieved by a resource-like class declaration.  If that's part of what you need to do then I think option 2 is the only viable approach.